# Count the number of blank cells below a non-blank cell

Tags: count, excel

I am working in Microsoft Excel 2013. In the screenshot below, I have a list of people's names (under **SURNAME** column) and the household they belong to (**New No.**). I would like Excel to count the number of people in each household, and enter it into the **HH Siz** column. One person, Ntuyu, lives in WC335. Two people, N. Dlakiya and Y. Dlakiya, live in WC415. I need a formula to do this automatically. Please help. Thanks.

[Screenshot of the excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swBrj.jpg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited for https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Put this in C2 and copy down the list:

```
=IF(A2<>"",COUNTA($B2:B$1048576)-SUM(C3:C$1048576),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott. I edited the post as I was struggling to implement your suggestion. Could you please make your suggestion specific to the new excel sheet inserted.

Comment: Scott, I actually applied a bit more effort and managed to figure it out. Your solution works. Thank you very much.